# What is the correct way to create branch in RCS, and do you need to set a lock first?

Tags: branch, checkin, rcs

I am looking for best practices using branches in RCS.

I had read the man page for `rcs` and `ci` and also browsed at the following links:

http://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/manual/html_node/Concepts.html

http://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/manual/html_node/Quick-tour.html

Suppose i have revision `1.3` on tip of the trunk.

I now want to change file `1.2` (as `1.3` have several other changes I cannot yet use).

I understand I can create branch on revision `1.2` using `ci -r1.2.1`

My question are the follows: 

1. Do I need to set a lock on the file? If so, on which revision?

2. If no lock set, I cannot use `-u` flag in order to keep the file in my local dir. In case I wish to do so, is it still possible without `co` the file again?

Side note: I feel RCS does not suit my company needs however migrating to another system is not my decision to make, so currently I need to keep working with it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm looking for much the same thing, but seeing as you've had no answers, I'll offer my current practice:

I use branches for development, not for keeping different variants going in parallel. I keep my best, presumably working, code on the trunk and try not to check in anything on it that might break it. I branch the code when I want to start a line of development that will take some time, that may leave it broken for a while, is an experiment I may abandon, etc.

To start a new line of development I change the default branch to a new branch off the trunk-rev to be the base of the new development line, and force a checkin onto that branch with

```
rcs -b1.2.1 foo.cpp
ci -f1.2.1 -l foo.cpp`
```

Now I can dive in to developing the branch, and my next check-ins will go onto the new branch instead of onto the trunk. Whether you lock a revision or not is only relevant to whether you intend to modify the working file.
You're correct that you can't keep both revisions, trunk-tip and branch-tip in the same folder; they have the same file name. But you can check out one of them with a `-p` switch (which will send the output to stdout instead of to a file) which you can then redirect into a sub-folder, or to a local file with a unique name.